# Numeric value not able to set as env using Dockerfile #27284

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

I'm trying to build a dockerimage from docker file,  i'm setting an ENV in the Dockerfile(ENV GOROOT "/usr/share/go/1.6").. But I couldn't find the same ENV value inside the container. The value is set as "/usr/share/go". "/1.6" is missing.

**Steps to reproduce the issue:**

1. build the Dockerfile https://gist.github.com/anumantharaja/afa1fc1684a58b2646e2ae2d80489686
2. Run the image
3. and inside the container give echo $GOROOT

**Result i received:**
i received /usr/share/go

**Result i expected:**
i expected /usr/share/go/1.6

Comment: I tried it with base image busybox (+ no extension on the Dockerfile) and than I got the expected result.

Comment: - lorenzvth7 are u tried this? This is working for u?

Comment: I'll show it in an answer. I can delete it after you've seen it

Answer (score 2):

Dockerfile

```
FROM busybox

###   Add Env
ENV GOPATH /root/.gopkg/
ENV GOROOT /usr/share/go/1.6
ENV PATH $PATH:$GOROOT/bin
```

Build the image

```
docker build -t rom .
```

Start a container from the image:

```
docker run -d -it rom /bin/sh
5dea13c392bcf8740d918be61e8d0c22d20835353a020111f467b928a8990e08
```

Go inside container

```
docker exec -it 5dea13c392bcf8740d918be61e8d0c22d20835353a020111f467b928a8990e08 /bin/sh
```

Echo the env var

```
/ # echo $GOROOT
/usr/share/go/1.6
```

This is not an answer. Just to show him that it worked in my case.
Maybe it isn't working with his base image.

Comment: Thks lorenzvth7.. Issue was in my side its now working fine... I hard code GOROOT /usr/share/go this value in .bashrc that was the issue...

Comment: I'm glad you found your issue.